# How to compute a pointer to member from an instance in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I'm doing a little library in C++ and I'm getting the problem below.

Knowing an instance of a class A. How much is it safe to compute a pointer to member from the difference of the instance address with its member address ?

Such I can reuse this pointer to member later, to access to the member of another instance.

My guess is it isn't safe as there is would be a cast, but in practice, would it be that much unsafe or is it reasonably safe ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Please show some code to explain what you are trying to do (and why). I can't think of a good use-case for such a calculation based on your description

Comment: Could you please clarify your specific use case? Usually one doesn't need pointer to members. If you're sure to need that, take a look at `offsetof()`.

Comment: That computation doesn't sound like a pointer-to-member; it sounds like an *offset-of-member*. Sometimes it is needed, though it is far, far more likely that the perceived "need" for it devolves to an underlying Y solution to an X problem.

Comment: Sounds like not a language-defined pointer-to-member, but taking `object * o_ptr` and `int * i_ptr` and calculating `i_ptr - o_ptr`. Then adding that difference to another `object*` to get another `int*`.

Comment: There are situations where it would work; there are situations where it would not. Don't do it.

Comment: @JaMiT It is exactly what I meant actually. I'm not a compiler expert so I don't know if all the instances of a given class always have the same memory layout or not at all. That was my question :)

Comment: Could you not just use a member pointer instead?

Comment: @Jojolastiti See how easy it is to come up with an example? Put some example code in your question (after the current text) so that others can more easily see what you mean.

Comment: The only way to get a pointer-to-member (i.e. a `member_type (Class::*)`) is by applying `&` to the member's qualified name (i.e. `&Class::member_name`). That is, what one might consider the opposite, `&(object.*pointer)`, does not have an inverse.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes your example is really intuitive. So it's just not possible. Many thanks everybody. :)

Comment: @Jojolastiti -- unintuitive as it may be, yes, it's possible for objects of the same type to have different memory layouts. Virtual bases can mess everything up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.